# How can I install the pylint for python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pylint

I try to install the pylint for the python2.7 which in ubuntu 18.04, but it raises an error with this words:

```
pip install pylint                                  
Collecting pylint
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/04/1f/1d3929051b45c3e4015178c5fe5bbee735fb4e362e0fc4f0fbf3f68647ad/pylint-2.1.1.tar.gz
pylint requires Python '>=3.4.*' but the running Python is 2.7.15
```

I have been used the `pip3` installed the pylint successfully for python3.6.

So, how can I install the pylint for python2.7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pylint still maintains support for Python 2 until maybe next year or so. But you need to install `1.9.X` instead of `2.X`. It seems though that you already had `pylint` installed, once you uninstall it you should be able to get 1.9 instead.

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Thanks for your help~

Comment: And we can use this command to install the last pylint version of 1.9.x for python2.7. `pip install pylint==1.9.3`.

Comment: And here is all the contribute version of pylint:

Comment: (from versions: 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.20.0, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.21.2, 0.21.3, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.24.0, 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.25.2, 0.26.0, 0.27.0, 0.28.0, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 2.0.0.dev0, 2.0.0.dev1, 2.0.0.dev2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, it is becoming more and more difficult to install Python libraries, but it is still possible if you take care to fix the dependencies' versions.

For PyLint, you should also fix the versions of `configparser` and `isort` which have been upgraded to Python 3.

So, the command to run is :

```bash
pip install "pylint<2" "configparser~=4.0.2" "isort~=4.3.21" "lazy-object-proxy~=1.6.0"
```

Note that here, with the `~=`, I used version constraints that would allow to install the latest bug fix of each library. But, you can also use a strict constraint with `==` as there is little chance that an update will be released for Python 2.7.

Here are the versions of the libraries installed to date (2020-07-12) by this command:

```bash
> pip freeze
astroid==1.6.6
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.6.4
configparser==4.0.2
enum34==1.1.10
futures==3.3.0
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==1.9.5
singledispatch==3.6.2
six==1.16.0
wrapt==1.12.1
```